# issue in lightbox effect in php

Tags: php, lightbox

I am using lightbox to show an image in php.

My current code:

```
<a class="sri" href="administrator/all_photo/mywork/
<?php 
    echo $res['path'];
?>
_1.jpg" rel="lightbox">
<img src="administrator/all_photo/mywork/
<?php 
    echo $res['path'];
?>
_1.jpg" class="photo_frame photo_size" >
<br />
<?php 
    echo $res['title'];
?>
</a>
```

CSS and JS for lightbox have already been included. In the above code, `$res['title']` and `$res['path']` are being fetched from database.

If I click on the image or the text which is showing as `$res['title']`, lightbox effect is showing. The image is within the lightbox. Now I need the `$res['title']` value also be displayed when the lightbox is opened along with the image.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `title` parameter in the `<a>` tag, as mentionned in the [Lightbox Documentation](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/):

> Optional: Use the title attribute if you want to show a caption.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the title:

```
<a class="sri" href="administrator/all_photo/mywork/
<?php 
    echo $res['path'];
?>
_1.jpg" rel="lightbox">
<img src="administrator/all_photo/mywork/
<?php 
    echo $res['path'];
?>
_1.jpg" title="
<?php 
    echo $res['title'];
?>
" class="photo_frame photo_size" >
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to move all of your markup into a div. Add rel="lightbox" to that div, it should work. Although that depends on the lightbox library you are using.